# A tale of two diffs: which one needs more TLC?

Tags: maintenance, differential, land-rover, lr3

### Background

My 2009 V8 LR3 has done around 150k km. It has a permanent 4WD system.

I have no record of prior drivetrain-related maintenance.

### Question

If I have to prioritize which diff's fluid to replace first (due to wear and tear), which one should it be?

Should it be:

- the ***rear diff***, as it is always transmitting torque to the wheels from the engine, or
- the ***front diff***, since it is sees more difference in rotational speed across the two output shafts (induced by steering), or
- ***both***, because diff fluid degradation is related to other causes?

Comment: What year is your LR3?

Comment: It's a 2009, the last year they made it I believe

Comment: Are the axles & differential gears still turning even when the 4X4 is not engaged?

Comment: That's a good question.  What's a good practical way to verify that?

Comment: Does the gearbox have a central diff lock? Because if it does then it should be permanent 4wd - the landrover may have gone to basically the same box as the RR before then - if not does it have front free-wheeling hubs?

Comment: When you say “LR3” this is what is really a Discovery ? If sonit has permanent four-wheel drive.

Comment: I suppose you could jack up the front and turn the wheels to see. I am not familiar with Land Rovers. Personally, I would just change them both to ensure they are good to go.

Comment: @SolarMike you're right. I hadn't realized that prior to asking the question. At least that should make the answer obvious...

Comment: @SolarMike upon reflection, the question is still valid. The rear diff will still see the lion's share of torque throughput and the front diff gets exercised more through steering. So the question boils down to which one sees more wear and tear

Comment: You should do some research about your own vehicle - it has a 50:50 torque split front / rear in normal conditions  see : http://www.fourwheeler.com/features/0501or-2005-land-rover-lr3/. So the rear does not see the “lion’s share”... You should change all the oil etc rear diff and bearings if necessary, transfer box and centre dif, gearbox as you are there, front dif and both front hub/ bearing assemblies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three - front, back and transfer box/centre diff. As it's a permanent 4WD system, all three diffs are in constant use, so if you've got no record of them being changed, it's probably worth doing all of them.

Saying that, what does the service schedule recommend?

I can't remember if the Discovery 3 still has traditional 'swivels' on the front axle, but if it does, I'd also recommend at least checking the oil/grease level in those.

Edit - I've just found that my local Land Rover specialist has a guide to servicing on their website:

[Keith Gott Service Schedule](http://www.keithgott.co.uk/service_schedule_discovery_3.html#schedule_headings)

Key points here are:

**60 months/ 75k miles:**

- Renew transfer box oil, replace drain and fill plug washers
- Renew locking differential oil

**120 months / 150k miles:**

- Renew manual gearbox oil
- Renew automatic transmission oil and filter
- Renew transfer box oil, replace drain and fill plug washers
- Renew front and rear axle oil
- Renew locking differential oil

So at roughly 93k miles, you don't actually need to do the axles yet, but you should do the transfer box and centre diff if it hasn't been done.

Comment: I don't have the service schedule handy at the moment, when I have it I'll update this post

Comment: @Zaid I've found a schedule online - see edit - though that's for UK, so yours might vary being in a hotter environment

Comment: The Discovery 1 was the last of the "traditional 'swivels'".  There is no oil or grease to check at the hubs from the Discovery 2 onward.  The bearing is also a single hub unit that bolts onto the hub carrier, so nothing to service there also.